# Spacy: Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda, conda, spacy

I'm trying to load the `en_core_web_sm` spaCy model, but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

The error that occurs is the following:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I'm working in a Anaconda virtual environment. The following checkboxes are ticked:

- Did `conda activate gcp-env` prior to installing spaCy and the english language model
- Have run `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` while on the right environment
- Then, have run `python -m spacy download en`, still while on the right environment
- Also tried adding `spacy` to the `requirements.txt` , and installing dependencies via that route, after first attempts failed

`spacy info` produces this output:

```
spacy info

============================== Info about spaCy ==============================

spaCy version    3.3.0                         
Location         /Users/simonmortensen/opt/anaconda3/envs/gcp-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy
Platform         macOS-11.6.5-x86_64-i386-64bit
Python version   3.10.4                        
Pipelines        en_core_web_sm (3.3.0)
```

`python -m spacy validate` produces this output:

```
================= Installed pipeline packages (spaCy v3.3.0) =================
ℹ spaCy installation:
/Users/simonmortensen/opt/anaconda3/envs/gcp-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy

NAME             SPACY                 VERSION                            
en_core_web_sm   >=3.3.0.dev0,<3.4.0   3.3.0   ✔
```

I've been through several previous StackOverflow posts on the same topic. Those have often been solved, but my issue remains.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Simon

EDIT:
For additional context, `pip list` on the environment contains both

```
spacy                         3.3.0
spacy-legacy                  3.0.9
spacy-loggers                 1.0.2
```

and

```
en-core-web-sm                3.3.0
```

Even so, `import en_core_web_sm` also doesn't work:

```
import en_core_web_sm
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [65] in <cell line: 1>
    import en_core_web_sm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'
```

Comment: try downloading that specific model: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Comment: I have also tried this, also unsuccessful, unfortunately

Comment: you could download the model to a specific location, and then load the model from that path.

Comment: Interesting! That sounds like a good idea. How do I choose the location it downloads to? Alternatively, find the location it's already downloaded to?

Comment: I tried the latter, without success. For the former, you can download the files with your browser from the git repo of spacy to wherever you choose.

Comment: This link seems relevant: `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/README.md`

Comment: Just in case: Does `import spacy; nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` work?

Comment: @warped, I can't find anything in that document that helps. Is there anything in specific that caught your attention?

Comment: @fsimonjetz, correct. That's when the errors occur.

Comment: Same issue on spaCy forums. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10895

Comment: Yea, that's me as well @polm23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spyder was the villain.

All packages were correctly installed on the virtual environment, but Spyder was not running that environment (even if the IDE was launched with the `spyder` command from a terminal where the environment was in fact activated).

In order to make Spyder run the correct environment, you needed to change the Python interpreter in the Spyder preferences:
[image]
... and then restart the kernel.

I got an error prompting me to `pip install spyder-kernels==2.1.*`, but once that was done (make sure to do it on the right venv), I restarted Spyder, and it finally worked!

See discussions in thread: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10895.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not taking the good path of the enviroment.

In a terminal exceute which python , and you have to validate is taking the enviorement paths.

Comment: ```which python``` produces 
```/Users/simonmortensen/opt/anaconda3/envs/gcp-env/bin/python```. This looks correct to me?